# UWP TextBlock Text doesn't change

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xbind

My goal was to make a list of selectable shows where the user can pick one, then edit data about it in the right panel.

I have an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to a `ListView`. The test `Show`s appear correctly. I also have a `Show SelectedShow` that is bound using `Mode.TwoWay`. When I select a different `Show` in the `ListView`, I receive the corresponding debug statement.

The `TextBlock`'s `Text` does not change when I click different `Show`s in the `ListView`.

Any ideas?

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="PlexHelper.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PlexHelper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="" PlaceholderText="Search shows..."/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Shows}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedShow, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Show">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind SelectedShow.Name, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace PlexHelper
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Show> Shows { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Show>();
        public Show SelectedShow { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Shows.Add(new Show("Show 1"));
            Shows.Add(new Show("Show 2"));
            Shows.Add(new Show("Show 3"));
            SelectedShow = Shows[0];
        }

        private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("now selected: " + SelectedShow.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Show.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace PlexHelper
{
    public class Show : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Show(string name = "Default Show Name")
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise PropteryChanged event for SelectedShow as well in order to reflect it on UI.

Your `MainPlage` should look like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ObservableCollection<Show> Shows { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Show>();

            private Show _selectedShow;
            public Show SelectedShow
            {
                get => _selectedShow;
                set
                {
                    if (_selectedShow != value)
                    {
                        _selectedShow = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                Shows.Add(new Show("Show 1"));
                Shows.Add(new Show("Show 2"));
                Shows.Add(new Show("Show 3"));
                SelectedShow = Shows[0];
            }

            private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("now selected: " + SelectedShow.Name);
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }
```

I would better recommend creating a ViewModel which contains the list of Shows along with the SelectedShow and Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in that VM.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I forgot something.

Comment: I Am glad that it helped.